# Calculating average power when given weird waveforms

Tags: power, ac

How would you approach calculating average power for a given voltage and current waveform?

I figured out that the general approach involves the integral of p(t) from 0 to the time of the first period of the two waveforms divided by the period. The problem with this is that the two waveforms are different from each other and don't have the same period.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't with current alone. Need either a voltage or a resistance to go with the current. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: Average power is always the mean of instantaneous power over some period. In this case I would compute over the whole waveform, since it is questionable whether or what the period is (may not be a periodic function).

Comment: Calculus using the voltage and current waveforms. Multiply both waveforms together to produce a power waveform, then find the average of that power waveform by calculating the area under the curve which gives you energy, then divdie by the time which gives you the average power.

Comment: \$\overline{P}=\frac{1}{t_1 - t_0}\int_{_{t_0}}^{^{t_1}} V_t\cdot I_t\:\:\textrm{d}t\$ and you get to specify the period over which the average is computed. Choose wisely.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an equation that describes these waveforms? 
The signals you show look like oscillograms of an actual signal.

If you can periodically sample the voltage and current signals, then the average power can be calculated as such:

$$ \overline{W} = {1 \over N} {\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} v_k i_k}  $$

Where:
\$ N \$ = number of samples
\$ v_k \$ = voltage at sample \$k\$
\$ i_k \$ = current at sample \$k\$

Comment: Yes. The average voltage and average current of a waveform with no DC component will be zero, but average power will always be positive, because the negative excursions of voltage and current are multiplied, providing a positive result.

Comment: No need for the last two sentences. If they are in phase in a resistive load then V and I are either both positive or both negative at any point in time and the resulting power waveform is always positive as a result.

Comment: @mkeith et. al. You guys are right. I deleted last paragraph. Chalk it up to jet lag.